# iPhone SDK Audio Mixer

Tags: iphone, objective-c, audio, mixer

What I need to do is be able to mix 4 channels of audio (not from a live source, just prerecorded audio files in the app bundle), and change their volumes individually, in real time, preferably with MP3s.  What's the best/correct road for me to take, regarding all the various sound APIs for the iPhone?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Storm Sim does this with AVAudioPlayer, which is certainly the simplest methdod. You can call prepareToPlay on each of the player objects then kick them off with play later so there won't be any delay. I also use a blank 1-second audio player on eternal loop to keep the deviceTime counting down, so you can use playAfter to give a specific deviceTime in the future to make all the samples play in-sync or offset relative to each other (deviceTime only ticks if there is some sort of audio playing). The AVAudioPlayerDelegate has interrupted/resumed events and finishedPlaying so you can get notification of what is happening.

However there is only one hardware MP3/AAC decoder, so the other three will use up CPU (and thus battery) doing the decoding. If you want to maximize battery life, use CAF files in IMA4@44100. It is about 1/4 the size of the raw WAV files so it isn't as good as MP3 but the performance is much better, especially if you are using a lot of small audio tracks. If you are using voice you can get away with much less fidelity and smash the files even more. afconvert in terminal can help you getting your source files in the CAF format (you should use CAF files no matter what the encoding).